# Can I host a WCF 4.0 Application in an IIS Website with a .NET 2.0 App Pool?

Tags: wcf

I was watching a [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Hosting-WCF-Services-in-IIS) from plural-sight on hosting a WCF service in IIS and the presenter creates an application under an existing IIS website to host the WCF Service.  I have a website that has an App Pool of version 2.0.  Can I use this website to add the WCF application or does it have to be a 4.0 app pool website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't, WCF 4.0 needs .NET 4.0/3.5 to work, period.

Comment: Does it need to be hosted as an application or can it be hosted as a website?

Comment: A HTTP WCF service hosted in IIS is just like a website with a URL address (default .svc), your App Pool needs to be created with correct .NET version/permissions and bound to the WCF service (the website).

Comment: The reason why I asked is because do I have to create a new website and then add a new application under that website or can I just create a new website that points directly to the service?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, from what I see here a WCF service needs an app pool to work; a CLR in the background, a fact. Now when you say "can I just create a new website that points directly to the service?" it makes me think that you are actually "creating" that new website which will bind to the application, in a way your two ways of doing it are practically the same.